# shortcut for table table>tr*2>td*3+tab is not working in sublime

Tags: sublimetext2

Hi I seen some sublime text 2's shortcuts which works fine, but table>tr*2>td*3 is not working . Is there anything new package I need to install? please let me know if any shortcuts that makes typing easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is syntax of zencoding.
you need to install package emmet for this to work.
https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to install angularjs package in sublime?

Comment: i am not entirely sure of what you are asking but you have to install the package manager for sublime from here https://sublime.wbond.net/installation and then press ctrl+shift+p and type package install and follow the instructions

Comment: Yeah i got it, but I am asking about angular.js package in sublime once i install it then i will get all the angular tags and service names as i type, just like auto complete.

Comment: @Sudarshan if you have a new question, then please [ask it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can browse available plugins at https://sublime.wbond.net or search using the search box.